# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 7

Tags: hibernate

When ever i tried to extratc a Float value , i am getting this Exception .
I am using MYSQL with Hibernate (Liferay)

Hibernate:

```
select IFNULL(a.deltatime,0),   b.vlid , a.TESTDATE  
from testresult a,XREFRTGTESTRESULT b 
where a.id = b.id
    and a.TESTDATE between '2011-06-01 22:03:01 ' AND   '2011-06-02 22:03:01 '  
    and a.id='51006'
```

```
 
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 7
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:368)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:150)
    at com.virtela.reports.drilldown.service.persistence.ReportsDrillDownMySQLFinderImpl.getVPNDrillDown(ReportsDrillDownMySQLFinderImpl.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Exception No Dialect mapping for JDBC type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083675/getting-exception-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type)

Answer (score 0):

This link might be pertinent:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=973997&view=next

A word of advice: I find it helpful to cut & paste my best guess as to root cause of an error into Google.  Chances are good that I'm not the first to encounter a particular problem.

---

Comment: I dont have any Mapping File , i have only Hibernate.cfg file , i am using it with Liferay .

Comment: I'm happy he posted instead of Googling as that is how answers are created.  This is the top search I got on Google.  Without anyone asking, the answer never gets indexed in the first place.

Comment: If he hadn't asked, perhaps the link I posted would have been on top.  Might have more to say about SO SEO practices than the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your class definition and Hibernate mapping? JDBC type 7 is java.sql.Types.REAL. You might need to specify float or double instead.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed since Hibernate 3.2.5: [HHH-2663](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2663). If you have to use older version of Hibernate, you can use one of the following options:

- Use different type in the database, such as `double`
- Add explicit cast to the query: `case(IFNULL(a.deltatime,0) as double)`
- Subclass the `Dialect` you use and register type `REAL` manually